# pinch scroll view zoom inside touchable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am having issues implementing a scroll view pinch zoom inside a touchable opacity. The scroll view must be a child of the touchable for this use case. any suggestions. The code for this is currently:

Image Component:

```
return (
                <ScrollView
                  maximumZoomScale={2}
                  onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
                  key={node.key}
                  style={{
                    width: "100%",
                  }}
                >
                  <FitImage {...imageProps} />
                </ScrollView>
              );
```

Then parent is roughly:

```
 <TouchableOpacity
        ref={this.accordian}
        style={styles.row}
        onPress={() => this.toggleExpand()}
      >
<ImageComponent/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Mainly focussing on the child image component. It now doesn't allow me to use zoom

Any Suggestions?

Thanks